# an algebra generated by some known series

Tags: co.combinatorics, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, generating-functions, enumerative-combinatorics

Denote the e.g.f. for the number of (unordered) rooted labeled trees on $n$ nodes by
$$\Phi(x)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n^{n-1}}{n!}x^n.$$
And, the related series $\Psi(x)=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{n^n}{n!}x^n$. Designate the operator $D:=x\frac{d}{dx}$. Some properties:

(1) $\Psi=D\Phi$;

(2) both $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ have radius of convergence $\frac1e$;

(3) (from Lagrange) $\Phi(x)$ is the inverse of $x(v)=ve^{-v}$;

(4) $(1-\Phi)(1+\Psi)=1$;

(5) $\Phi^k(x)=k\sum_{n\geq j}\frac{n^{n-k-1}}{(n-k)!}x^n$.

> **Questions.**
>
> (a) Is there anything interesting that can be said about the algebra $\mathcal{A}=\mathbb{Q}[\Phi,\Psi]$?
>
> (b) In view of (4) above, what about the quotient of $\mathcal{A}$ by the relation $\Phi\Psi-\Psi+\Phi$?

Comment: e.g.f= exponential generating function

Comment: $-\Phi(-x)$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: A first natural place to look for an answer would be in the OEIS in which one would find this classic tree function http://oeis.org/A000169 with several references and links to other sequences, including the reference by Zvonkine noted in the answer by Chapoton (entered 13 years ago!) as well as one of Chapoton's. Why several heavy users of this venue neglect the OEIS is a matter of interesting speculation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been considered by Dimitri Zvonkine, see his article "An algebra of power series arising in the
intersection theory of moduli spaces of curves
and in the enumeration of ramified coverings
of the sphere" (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403092.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, that was quick. I am still hoping for an answer to part (b) which does not seem to appear in the above paper.

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000169